# When I use mongodb query operator, it returns cursor object

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am learning to use mongodb and i had a problem.

I am using [query operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/) and normally it should return documents from collection. However it returns a `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` object.

Here is my code:

```py
result = collection.find({
    "school_score" : {
        "$gt" : 80
    }
})
print(result)
```

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000001F0BD902250>
```

In the video that i watched, everything is normal. On the other hand, I don't get datas.

Edit: I only encountered cursor object when I used query operator with $ sign in find method, other times when I used find method, i got datas. Also, in the course video, teacher wrote exactly same code as above but cursor object is not returned.

Comment: Find returns a cursor instance, which then you can iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo's `find` just returns a cursor, from the [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find):

> Returns an instance of Cursor corresponding to this query.

If you want to make it a list just wrap it with `list()`:

```
result = list(collection.find({
    "school_score" : {
        "$gt" : 80
    }
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,
I want to ask one more thing. 
In the beginning of course;
````
for i in collection.find():
    print(i)
````
this code returns datas not cursor object.

I only encountered cursor object when I used query operator with $ sign, other times when I used find method, everything was normal.

Comment: Yes, cursor is a generator, so when you iterate over it you get "datas".